# Java nio read chars and ints binary on the same line

Tags: java, binary, nio

I'm trying to get a grip on java.nio and got stuck on reading from a binary file, previously written
single line "on on on748".

I use try with resources so I'm sure that file and channel are ok.

On the bytebuffer ,declared and allocated 12 that being channel size.

Here the problem starts cause on my bytearray ,I can read it with a for each
 and char casting and with a for i can't seem to get any method to adress the numbers.

I've tried a second buffer with .get(xx,8,2) but I don't know how to turn the byte[] array of 2 to an int.

```
try(FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
        FileChannel channel = file.getChannel()){

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((12));

        channel.read(buffer);
        byte[] xx = buffer.array();

        System.out.println(xx.length);
        for (byte z:xx) {
            System.out.println((char)z);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
                if (i<8)
                    System.out.print((char)xx[i]);
                if (i>=8)
                    System.out.println((int)xx[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Your number isn't binary - it's just 3 ASCII digits '7', '4' and '8'. What's the benefit of using ByteBuffer for you, when you're just converting it to an array? What's the reason for not using InputStream or Reader/BufferedReader (or Scanner) ?

Comment: Well you might be right. I've written the line using Bytebuffer. I saw on the channel size 12, I inferred that on a 0 index array  the 12 position being /0